# JS change nested property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to change a nested variable property. First check if it exists then change it to 'N/A' if necessary. This is what I have.

```
const json = {
 isCat: {
    isAvaliable: true,
    count: 5
  },
  isDog: {
    isAvaliable: true,
    count: 10
  },
  isFrog: {
    isAvaliable: false,
    count: null
  }
}

const newJson = { ...json }
if(!jsonObj.isCat.count) {
    newJson = {...newJson, json.isCat.count: 'N/A'}
}
```

Im not sure how to set count lets say by goign directly to it and changing the value. It seems simple maybe im missing something.

I can see the value in the if statement but i cant make any changes to the actual property value itself. Basically if a value is null, change it to 'N/A'

Comment: You should keep the data as `null` and only render `N/A` on the page, unless it's some API that's expecting a string with N/A, but then, it would be a poor API...

Comment: Are you sure ypu want to change the data for count to be a string `N/A`? Surely leaving it as null is better, or maybe setting it to 0.

Comment: Thats what Im doing. Its on the frontend

Comment: `newJson` is also `const`, so the reassignment won't work either.

Comment: You've tagged the question with [reactjs], is this data in the state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: You don't change the data to something that is ready to render, you just render something based on the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array reduce** method. First get all the keys using **Object.keys** method. Then traverse the keys and check the count is null or not. If null then change it to 'N/A'.

```js
const json = {
  isCat: {
    isAvaliable: true,
    count: 5,
  },
  isDog: {
    isAvaliable: true,
    count: 10,
  },
  isFrog: {
    isAvaliable: false,
    count: null,
  },
};

const ret = Object.keys(json).reduce((prev, c) => {
  const p = prev;
  if (!json[c].count) p[c] = { ...json[c], count: 'N/A' };
  else p[c] = { ...json[c] };
  return p;
}, {});
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: I get an error basically, json is a param in method. Cant assign param erro

Comment: You may be did something wrong. The code should work.

Comment: May be you are facing object mutation problem. I have fixed it and it will return a new object. Now check it.

Comment: Another problem I have is that what if there is no object altogether like no isFrog exists. I want to be able to still set count

Answer (score 1):

Using Object.entries and Object.fromEntries you can map the old object to the new object. If the `count` property is truthy, i.e. not `null` then map it through, otherwise shallow copy the element and update the `count` property with the new `"N/A"` value. This avoids mutating your original object.

```
const newJson = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(json).map(([key, value]) => ([
  key,
  value.count ? value : { ...value,
    count: 'N/A'
  }
])));
```

```js
const json = {
  isCat: {
    isAvaliable: true,
    count: 5
  },
  isDog: {
    isAvaliable: true,
    count: 10
  },
  isFrog: {
    isAvaliable: false,
    count: null
  }
};

const newJson = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(json).map(([key, value]) => ([
  key,
  value.count ? value : { ...value,
    count: 'N/A'
  }
])));

console.log(newJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with reduce. Beware of it's comma operator in the return value.

```js
const json = {isCat: {isAvaliable: true,count: 5,},isDog: {isAvaliable:true,count: 10,},isFrog: {isAvaliable: false,count: null,},};

const res = Object.keys(json).reduce((pV,cV)=>(json[cV].count==null?json[cV].count='N/A':null,json),{});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What if isCat doesnt exist and I still want to set isAvailable to false for example

Comment: then it would be better to use Object.entries() instead of Object.key() where you can check for the current key name == isCat